# MSQL count winners and include 0 winners

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, mysql-workbench

I have a problem with my query. I just started SQL recently. In the first table below, I want to count the number of teams that won the most and include teams that have zero wins as well. The table names are highlighted in red.

[image: TABLE NAMES]

I want my query result to look like the second image i attached, or like this

```
Phenix  2
StarWar 1
Strack  1
Serious 0
Apolo   0
APTX    0
Poki    0
```

[image: Final result]

So far my best Query is:

```
   SELECT t1.Team_Name
        , COUNT(winner) AS TotalWins
     FROM result r 
LEFT JOIN team_1 t1
       ON r.Team1_ID = t1.Team1_ID
 GROUP BY winner

          UNION

   SELECT t2.Team_Name
        , COUNT(distinct winner) AS TotalWins
     FROM result r 
LEFT JOIN team_2 t2
       ON r.Team2_ID = t2.Team2_ID
 GROUP BY Winner
 ORDER BY TotalWins DESC;
```

The result I got doesn't include teams with zero wins, It just adds 1 for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

union your `team` tables first before joining the result table, then you can use `sum()` function to get the `total wins`.

```
select t1.Team_Name, sum(case when coalesce(t2.battle_no, '') = '' then 0 else 1 end) as TotalWins
from (select Team_Name, team1_id as id from team_1
    union all 
    select Team_Name, team1_id as id from team_1) t1
left join result t2 on t2.Team2_ID = t1.team1_id or t2.Team1_ID = t1.team1_id
```

Answer (score 0):

change the left table from result to the team for both teams

```
SELECT t1.Team_Name, COUNT(winner) AS TotalWins
     FROM team_1 t1 LEFT JOIN  result r 
    ON r.Team1_ID = t1.Team1_ID
    GROUP BY winner
    UNION
    SELECT t2.Team_Name, COUNT(distinct winner) AS TotalWins
    FROM team_2 t2 LEFT JOIN  result r
    on r.Team2_ID = t2.Team2_ID
    GROUP BY Winner
    ORDER BY TotalWins DESC
```